# AsyncTask's doInBackground(Params… params) sending different types of parameters

Tags: android, android-asynctask, parameters

I need something like this.. String params and Context in the same time..

```
protected String doInBackground(String... strings, Context ctx) {

    this.dhn = new DataHelper(ctx);
    this.dhn.Yaz(strings[0]);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just made this;

```
protected String doInBackground(Object... arguments) {
this.dhn = new DataHelper((Context) arguments[0]);
}
```